# Embedded document causes duplicate key error in the other collection mongodb nestjs

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I’m working with Mongodb and Nest Js.I have 2 schema X and Y. In X there is a property

```
export class X{
@Prop({required:true,unique:true})
email:string
}
```

which stops duplicates for the same email when try to create a document of X.

And In schema Y, X is embedded in Y schema. I have this in Y schema

```
export class Y{
@Prop({})
name : string;

@Prop({required:true})
x : X 
}
```

Now When I create first Y document with embedding X, it creates first Y document, but when I try to create an other Y with different name , but with same X document, the property email in the X schema throws `E11000 duplicate error.`

I’m just embedding the `X`, i’m not creating a new X document, Why it is throwing error when I try to create Y document, why the email `unique:true`, is effecting Y schema, while I’m just simply embedding it. Why mongo is creating indexes in the second collection as well, when I didn't mentioned?

I know by referencing X documents in Y , solves the problem. But I want to embed X document.
**Is there a way to stop mongo to create unique index in the Y collection of the X property?**

Comment: How are you saving these documents to the db?

Comment: I take `id` from client, find the `X` document by the `id` from db, and then `Y.x = X_document_from_db`.And after that, mongo creates `index` for the `email` in the `Y` collection as well. And I can't `embed` the same `X` document.

Comment: If `X` and `Y` is confusing for you, you can think like that  `X as Admin` , and , `Y as Customer` , and we have to keep track of which admin is the parent or creator of the customer.  So one `X or Admin` can be parent of multiple `Y or Customers`.